# Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I am attempting to install a network management package called cacti onto Ubuntu running under Windows Virtual PC. I attempted to install MySQL as it is one of cacti's dependencies. I can install and start the MySQL server, but whenever I try to access it in any other way, such as to change the password, I get the error message **Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO).** I would like to know what is causing this and how to fix it.

Edit: (just in case my comments are not visible) The answers from HD and Devin Ceartas did not work for me.

Comment: What is the command you are using?

Comment: The command is: mysql -u root

Comment: Same problem with -h127.0.0.1  appended to that?

Comment: yes, I get the same problem

Comment: 'telnet localhost 3306' opens a connection?

Comment: I seem to get a connection and then it says Connection closed by foreign host

Comment: That is from within the VM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try reseting the password with [these instructions](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/442).

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to connect to the MySQL server without a password. If you forgot it, you could try with:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server
```

A dialog box will ask you for a new root user password. If you're connecting with the mysql client you need to try:

```
mysql -p
```

This command will ask you for the password, you enter before.

Comment: When I tried the first, nothing happened after I put in my sudo password.

When I tried the second, it gave me "Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:YES)." I do not remember ever setting a root password

Comment: Which version of mysql-server have you installed?

Comment: How do I find this out?

Comment: dpkg -l | grep -i mysql-server

Comment: version 5.0.51a

Comment: Try sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.0 . Also in ubuntu, there is an admin user you can find it in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf (with the password)

Answer (score 1):

If you have never set a root password for MySQL, and you are in a fresh install normally the server does not require a password at all for connecting as root. 
To setup root password for first time, use mysqladmin command at shell prompt as follows:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

However, if you want to change (or update) a root password:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root -p'OLDPASSWORD' password NEWPASSWORD
```

If you lose the mysql server password you can use dpkg-reconfigure.

Comment: When I do this I get: mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO)

Comment: mean that the root password was set, if you have root privilege please refer to ~/.mysql_history file, it must contain the history of sql commands

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
shell> mysqladmin --user=root create cacti
```

---

Instead, create the MySQL database:

```
shell> mysqladmin --user=root --password create cacti
```

then type your password for the mysql root user.